# Count Number of occurrences of column values in DataTable - Tricky

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, counter

I need to count the number of occurrences of several different columns. For example my DataTable Columns are as below, they are just string and date types

```
[Case___], [Status],[Summary] ,[Description], 
[assigned_group], [Assigned_Individual], [Alert_Status],
[Date_Time_Created], [Date_Time_Resolved] ,
[Date_Time_Closed] ,[Data_Output_Type]
```

For each ****Assigned_Individual** I need to count

The number of times that this person had a **Status of Resolved || Closed**,

The number of times this person had an **Alert_Status = 'SLA Alert'  AND Status <> 'Resolved' AND Status <> 'Closed'**

The Number of times this person had an **Alert_Status = 'SLA Missed' AND Data_Output_Type = 'Active Tickets'**

My goal is to return a DataTable or List with records such as below

**Assigned_Indivual  -  Resolved  -  SLA Alert  -  SLA Missed**

bob, 5, 1, 4
Mary, 2,1,3
Ashley, 7,0,3

Im just looking for direction at this point as I Know I will likely need to use LINQ I cannot even comprehend a way to do this.

Thank you in advance Stack Oracles!

Im able to get the number of times an person has Status == "Resolved" || Status == "Closed" using the code below

```
var groupedData = from b in dt.AsEnumerable()
                          where b.Field<string>("Status") == "Resolved" || b.Field<string>("Status") == "Closed"
                          group b by new
                          {
                              Assigned_Individual = b.Field<string>("Assigned_Individual"),
                              Status = b.Field<string>("Status"),
                              assigned_group = b.Field<string>("assigned_group")
                          }
                              into g

                              let Counter = g.Count()
                              select new
                              {
                                  Assigned_Individual = g.Key.Assigned_Individual,
                                  Status = g.Key.Status,
                                  assigned_group = g.Key.assigned_group,
                                  Count = Counter
                              };
```

Which returns a count such as bob, 5 OR Mary, 2
But I need to know how to do this without using a where condition so that I can count my 3 conditions listed above.

Comment: the columns occur only once.. based on what you have posted.. are you looking for the number of `Rows` where those conditions are stated..? this is a pretty simple thing to do in regards to what you are wanting to return can you also show us what you have tried on your own vs expecting someone to do the work / give you the answer...

Comment: Absolutley, Im able to get the first condition using the code below. This will return how many times the status is == "Resolved" || "Closed"

Comment: then you should be able to do the rest.. not sure what the issue is..

Comment: Ive explained deeper above, sorry if it was unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Make a datatable Result
var dtResult = new DataTable();
dtResult.Columns.Add("Assigned_Indivual");
dtResult.Columns.Add("Resolved");
dtResult.Columns.Add("SLA Alert");
dtResult.Columns.Add("SLA Missed");

// Get All assigneds
var assigneds = dTable.AsEnumerable().Select(a => a.Field<string>("Assigned_Individual")).Distinct();

foreach(var assigned in assigneds)
{
    // Get All results os assigned indexed
    var resultOfAssigned = dTable.AsEnumerable().Where(a => a.Field<string>("Assigned_Individual") == assigned).ToList();

    // Count of results
    var resultResolved = resultOfAssigned.Where(a => a.Field<string>("Status") == "Closed").Count();
    var resultAlert = resultOfAssigned.Where(a => a.Field<string>("Alert_Status") == "SLA Alert" && a.Field<string>("Status") == "Resolved" && a.Field<string>("Status") == "Closed").Count();
    var resultMissed = resultOfAssigned.Where(a => a.Field<string>("Alert_Status") == "SLA Missed" && a.Field<string>("Data_Output_Type") == "Active Tickets").Count();

    // Define a data row
    var dRow = dtResult.NewRow();
    dRow[0] = assigned;
    dRow[1] = resultResolved;
    dRow[2] = resultAlert;
    dRow[3] = resultMissed;

    // Insert datarow in Datatable result
    dtResult.Rows.Add(dRow);
}
```

;)

Comment: How you did that, I have no idea Thank You! So you recreate the data table and values are distict for each person which is then in turn converted into a list variable then its a matter of counting. This worked great, ive been stuck all day and you did this in a matter of minutes thank you